# Missing identifier name in WinDbg display

Tags: windbg, masm

I'm inspecting a 64-bit executable using WinDbg(AMD64). 
This is the assembly code that I'm assembling using ML64 to create my executable:

_data SEGMENT

b DWORD 0

a DWORD 0

_data ENDS

_text SEGMENT

main PROC

```
lea rax, a
mov dword ptr [rax], 1

lea rbx, b
mov dword ptr [rbx], 1

mov eax, dword ptr [rax]
add dword ptr [rbx], eax

inc eax

imul eax, dword ptr [rbx]
mov dword ptr [rbx], eax

ret
```

main ENDP

_text ENDS

END

And this is my ML64 command:

ml64.exe e:\Assembly\WindowsDebugging\PointersProject\PointersProject.asm  /link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /ENTRY:main /DEBUG /OPT:NOREF,NOICF,NOLBR

All is well up to this point. But when I load this executable and disassemble the main function, the identifiers (a and b) are missing and I see <PERF> instead:

0:000> uf main

PointersProject!main:

```
00007ff7`b6211010 lea     rax,[PointersProject!main <PERF> (PointersProject+0x4004) (00007ff7`b6214004)]
00007ff7`b6211017 mov     dword ptr [rax],1
00007ff7`b621101d lea     rbx,[PointersProject!main <PERF> (PointersProject+0x4000) (00007ff7`b6214000)]
00007ff7`b6211024 mov     dword ptr [rbx],1
00007ff7`b621102a mov     eax,dword ptr [rax]
00007ff7`b621102c add     dword ptr [rbx],eax
00007ff7`b621102e inc     eax
00007ff7`b6211030 imul    eax,dword ptr [rbx]
00007ff7`b6211033 mov     dword ptr [rbx],eax
00007ff7`b6211035 ret
```

I was expecting to see something like this instead for the LEA lines:

```
    00000001`40001010 488d05ed2f0000  lea     rax,[PointersProject!a (00000001`40004004)]
    00000001`4000101d 488d1ddc2f0000  lea     rbx,[PointersProject!b (00000001`40004000)]
```

What does <PERF> mean? Why is WinDbg not showing the identifiers ? Is it because of some optimization during the build process ? If so how do I avoid it ? Please help.

Comment: Try adding /Zi to include symbolic debug info.

Comment: Yes, with /Zi it is working properly.

Comment: [Perf is performance optimized code if c or c++ use /Od iirc ml shouldn't optimize use /Zi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-performance-optimized-code)